# Overwrite Read-Only Touch Position Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to overwrite a read-only variable to simulate fingertouch with mouse in my code:

```
Touch fakeTouch = new Touch();
fakeTouch.position = Input.mousePosition;
```

The error I am getting is:

> `UnityEngine.Touch.position` cannot be assigned to (it is read only).

How can I change it to public or so to overwrite it?

Here is what I want to do in the reply: [Convert UnityEngine.Vector3 to UnityEngine.Touch or mouse input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47321201/convert-unityengine-vector3-to-unityengine-touch-or-mouse-input)

Comment: `UnityEngine.Touch.position` shouldn't be declared as read-only, as it contains both a `get` and a `set` accessor. Could it be that your example is out of context?

Comment: Where can I look this up please? Wait a minute I will post more code

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio you can just hover over the `position` property of the `Touch` object. Otherwise, you can look it up in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html).

Comment: using UnityEngine;
                using System.Collections;
                using System.Collections.Generic;
                using UnityEngine.UI;
                using System;

                public class TouchManager2 : MonoBehaviour {

                 void Update ()
                 {

                  print ("Test");
                  
                  Touch fakeTouch = new Touch ();
                  fakeTouch.position = Input.mousePosition;

                 }
                }

Comment: How can I add code comment?

Comment: I only see "get;" not set :( ???
https://i.imgur.com/WdkOP2Y.png

Comment: That's weird. Which Unity version are you using?

Comment: You can mark text as code in a comment by using the `` characters.

Comment: Unity5 because I need some effects not there in 2017

Comment: It works for me though, in Unity 2017.3. https://imgur.com/daC4YIZ

Comment: What effects do you need that aren't there in 2017?

Answer (score 0):

In Unity 5.6, you cannot overwrite the position field in the `Touch` class, since it is used as a C++-compatible container structure and not intended to be created directly in the runtime.

Define a `public sealed class TouchEx` that contains the fields you need, and bypass the `Touch` object in your own code.